What are the benefits and drawbacks of some ways to work around the ambiguous `operator==` issue in C++20 (with CRTP inheritance)?
I have a CRTP base class CRTPBase<Child, T> from which inherits the child class Child<T>. My goal is to be able to compare two values of type Child<T> using operator==. However, I found that when I only defined a operator== (const Child<T> &child) const inside CRTPBase<Child, T>, I got a warning about the ambiguity of operator== (I know this is specific to C++20 and after). As a result, I've been looking for other options to define such an equality operator. Here is what I have found so far:
template <template <typename> class Child, typename T>
struct CRTPBase {
    int a, b, c;  // Some fields

    // Option #1 for operator==; take in a const ref to CRTPBase<Child, T> and default it
    bool operator== (const CRTPBase<Child, T> &other) const = default;

    // Option #2 for operator==; take in a Child<T> directly. To avoid ambiguity, also
    // define the `friend` function
    bool operator== (const Child<T> &other) const {
        return (a == other.a) && (b == other.b) && (c == other.c);
    }

    friend bool operator== (const Child<T> &c1, const Child<T> &c2) {
        return (c1.a == c2.a) && (c1.b == c2.b) && (c1.c == c2.c);
    }

    // Option #3: Define <=>. Might be overkill?
    auto operator<=>(const CRTPBase&) const = default;
};

Are the options I listed correct? If so, what are the benefits and drawbacks of each option, in order to achieve the simple goal of being able to compare two Child<T>s using operator==?

"what are the benefits and drawbacks of each option...." looks like a list type question

Why is it the responsibility of CRTPBase to compare Child instances in the first place? What if e.g. Child adds a data member that should participate in this comparison, but that of course CRTPBase doesn't know about? Your "option #1" is the only one that makes sense to me.

@IgorTandetnik Good point. In this specific case, you can assume that no Child class will add any extra data members. The CRTPBase class only exists to define operations upon the Child classes in a single place, so I don't have to copy-paste the same thing for different child classes.

Isn't the friend version alone enough?

In this case, the "option 1" alone should be enough. Show a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the ambiguity issue you are supposedly observing.

Do you need the T parameter to reproduce the ambiguity? It looks like a needless complication to me.
